# How to get all jobs for current user and view every job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

> Missing keys required [:id] for child association show path

I have a job model that belongs to a user. In the user show page, I call all child jobs that belong to the user. Here is my code:

```
<% current_user.jobs.each do |j| %>
  <%= j.id %>
  <%= j.job_category %> 
  <%= link_to 'show', job_path(j.id) %> <br> <br>
<% end %>
```

But it raises an error anytime I click on show jobs page:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Please, how do I rectify this error? the routes show jobs resources stands on its own with path: job_path. it works when I manually plug in the URL.

Here are my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :jobs
  resources :applications
end

resources :jobs do 
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'jobs#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end 
end
```

and my controller code is:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @q = Job.ransack(params[:q])
      @jobs = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end 

  def frontpage
    @q = Job.ransack(params[:q])
      if params[:q].present?
        redirect_to jobs_path(@q)
      end
    @jobs = Job.all
  end 

  def search
    index
    render :index
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end


  def edit 
  end

  def update
    @joblists.update(joblists_params)
    redirect_to joblists_path
  end 

  def create 
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
    @user_job = @user.jobs.create(joblists_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Job has been successfully Created"
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end 

  def joblists_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_category, :job_title, :company_name, :location, :job_description,
      :monthly_salary, :deadline, :contact, :longitude, :lattitude, :full_time ) 
  end

end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add question clearly...

Comment: anytime I click on show link, it throws the error i have displayed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look after running `rails routes` it showing like this

```
user_job GET    /users/:user_id/jobs/:id(.:format)        jobs#show
```

so the link path is

```
user_job_path
```

on this link, you need to pass the `user_id` and job `id` then it will like this

```
<%= link_to 'show', user_job_path(@user, j.id) %> # or @user.id
```

**Solved after chat**

```
<% current_user.jobs.each do |j| %> 
    <%= j.id %> 
    <%= j.job_category %> 
    <%= link_to 'show', user_job_path(current_user.id, j.id) %> <br><br> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: this still throws this error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Have you used `@user.id` to the link like this `user_job_path(@user.id, j.id)`

Comment: yeah.. throws this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Then what is the `@user` object on your view? please clarify this

Comment: the view is the user show page. @user is the current user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170842/discussion-between-fool-dev-and-priince-abalogu).

Answer (score 0):

Add user id

```
user_job_path(current_user.id, j.id)
```

Thanks for comment

Comment: This will not work. `user_job_path` should, but first you need to understand the question.